# How to extend interface's fields names but not types

Tags: typescript

Say I have an interface

```
interface FooStr {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

I want another interface **to have exactly the same fields** as interface `FooStr` but with some other types.

Something like this:

```
interface FooNum extends FooStr {
  a: number; //good
  b: number; //good
  c: number; // not allowed because not in 'FooStr'
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: `Record<keyof FooStr, number>` should be the type you are looking for. no need to write it out again. Maybe put if in a type alias, or have an interface extend it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The simplest solution** (credits to @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir)

```
interface FooStr {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

type FooNum = Record<keyof FooStr, number>;
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GUxWQbwChlk4AuZAZ11AHMBuY5AIwuqjsYF9DCwBPAA4oM6AHIBXALbIAvMgBKEBOigATADwBrCP3Qw0mHFAA0yENObQAfI0IqQ1ZDEwVRkmfKIlyyAIwmTKzIAEyEXEA)

**The solution for adding a new field**

```
interface FooStr {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

type FooNum = Record<keyof FooStr, number> & {c: boolean};

const foo: FooNum = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: false //<--- added field "c" with "boolean" type
}
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GUxWQbwChlk4AuZAZ11AHMBuY5AIwuqjsYF9DCwBPAA4oM6AHIBXALbIAvMgBKEBOigATADwBrCP3Qw0mHFAA0yENObQAfMgBkBBBWaYANhDggujQipDVkGEwKUUkZeSIScmQARhMmVmQAJniSJ0C4V0oIQi4gA)

*Limitation*: cannot redefine property (if it's already defined in `FooStr`)

**An alternative solution** (credits to @VLAZ):

```
interface FooStr {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b: string;
}

type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  readonly [Property in keyof Type]: number;
};

type FooNum = OptionsFlags<FooStr>;

const fooNum: FooNum = {
  a: 1111,
  b: 2222
};
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAMQPYYMoRsAbwChhSyYoEATDMAGwE9gEAuYAZz3AHMBuEsqQrVajYACM2nGD36CAvgNJLgEBgAdUAeXUQQtdmjoJu7ADwAVDVAB8wALyEVQyjXpMA2gAUYGTTDVQMGAAaygGDDhgK00AXTYwAFcAW3FYOTJ5DOVBNU10LAA5FIdgHT0DIxNzTBw8G2zgFSQDCGA4IpS2WuLk0uJBUlZgAEYxkYAaZwk2ACZ52ZUsoA)

**+Solution that allows you to redefine properties**

In case you need to redefine a property from `FooStr`:

```
interface FooStr {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b: string;
  readonly c: string; // <--- I want this to be "boolean"
}

//first I exclude property `c`
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  readonly [Property in keyof Type as Exclude<Property, 'c'>]: number;
};

//then create a union type with a new `c` definition
type FooNum = OptionsFlags<FooStr> & { readonly c: boolean };

const asd: FooNum = {
  a: 1111,
  b: 2222,
  c: false // <---- works like a charm
};
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GUxWQbwChlkoI4ATdEAGwE9k4AuZAZ11AHMBuY08qrQYAjFuyhdeJMpWr1kCMRxA9CAX0KEwdAA4oA8jrDBqrVDTidWAHgAquiAD5kAXgJ8Zg%20QG0AClHQ9KG1kUGQAawg6dBhkez1GVmQAUQAPBBoAVwoIa39A6G0AGmQAcgRSxwBdFhBMgFthaF41Xi0HNEwAOQbXZENjU3NLGwxsXGcAMgJ%20WSEFFmFMGnIQZFbNBFMwRIoWMZ76vqISZmQARkvzor5RZAAmR-ubkkVkeBpWCHVuIA)